To validate that at least one field is filled out in the form (either the checkbox or the otherText field), if both empty show error in Angular?
To validate that at least one field is filled out in the form (either the checkbox or the "otherText" field), create a custom validator for the form group. This validator will check if at least one checkbox is selected or if the "otherText" field is filled out.  how can i do it
*I want to create form with two fields checkbox and other is otherText and if both is empty it have to show error *

i have create one function for validate at least one field is required but it is not working, please suggest any solution or if any problem in it *
*/component.ts
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  import { AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, ValidationErrors, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
  import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

  function atLeastOneFieldValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const checkboxValues = Object.values(control.value).filter(value => value === true);
    const otherTextValue = control.get('otherText') !.value;
    if (checkboxValues.length === 0 && !otherTextValue) {
      return { atLeastOneFieldRequired: true };
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-pop-up',
    templateUrl: './pop-up.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./pop-up.component.css']
  })
  export class PopUpComponent {
    checkboxForm: FormGroup;
    checkboxOptions = ['Custamizable', 'Price', 'Lead `enter code here`Team','Composatable','Biodegradable'];

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      const formControls = this.checkboxOptions.reduce((acc:any, option) => {
        acc[option] = [false];
        return acc;
      }, {});

      this.checkboxForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        ...formControls,
        otherText: ['', Validators.required]
      }, { validators:  atLeastOneFieldValidator });

    }


    onSubmit() {
      const selectedNames = Object.keys(this.checkboxForm.value).filter(key => this.checkboxForm.value[key]);
      console.log(selectedNames);
      console.log('Other Text:', this.checkboxForm.value.otherText);
    }
  }



component.html
 <div class="body-container">
  <h3>What Matters to You Most ?</h3>
  <h4>Select from the following options</h4>
  <div >
    <form [formGroup]="checkboxForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div *ngFor="let option of checkboxOptions">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="option">
          {{ option }}
        </label><br>
      </div>
    <div class="others-container">
      <label class="others-label">Others</label>
      <input class="others-input" type="text" placeholder="Type here..." formControlName="otherText"   ><br>
      </div>

      <div *ngIf="checkboxForm.errors && checkboxForm.errors['atLeastOneFieldValidator']">
        <p style="color: red;">At least one field must be filled out.</p>
      </div>

    <div class="buttonGroup">
      <!-- <button class="buttonCancle" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button> -->
      <button class="buttonSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>

</div>

</div>


Typo error, should be checkboxForm.errors['atLeastOneFieldRequired']. Your atLeastOneFieldValidator returns error with "atLeastOneFieldRequired" key.
